# How do I assign scores to students in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I'm creating this Student management system in Laravel, I'm done with student management feature where teachers can perform CRUD on students, and same as subjects. However I need to create an assessment feature that will allow teachers to assign scores to students after each class activity. I have been able to create something but it's not working at all, tried all forms of debugging but can't figure out why it's not working. I need help. This is what I have so far.

And currently when I try to create a new assessment, I receive this error. `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'student_id' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into` assessments `(`assessment_name`,` score`,` score_over`,` user_id`,` updated_at`,` created_at`) values (Homework11, 30,24, 40, 1, 2023-04-07 18:02:42, 2023-04-07 18:02:42))`

`// AssessmentController store() method`

```
public function store(StoreAssessmentRequest $request)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    // Create the assessment instance
    $assessment = new Assessment();
    $assessment->assessment_name = $validated['assessment_name'];
    $assessment->score = implode(',', $validated['score']);
    $assessment->score_over = $validated['score_over'];
    $assessment->user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    // Save the assessment instance to the database
    if (!$assessment->save()) {
        // handle error, for example:
        return back()->withInput()->withErrors(['error' => 'Failed to save assessment']);
    }

    $assessment_id = $assessment->id;

    // Save the subject for the assessment
    $subject = Subject::where('name', $validated['subject'])->firstOrFail();
    $assessment->subjects()->syncWithoutDetaching($subject->id);

    // Save the scores for each student
    foreach ($validated['score'] as $student_id => $score) {
        $student = Student::findOrFail($student_id);
        $assessment->students()->syncWithoutDetaching([
            $student->id => [
                'score' => $score,
                'subject_id' => $subject->id,
                'assessment_id' => $assessment_id,
                'student_id' => $student_id,
            ]
        ]);
    }

    return redirect()->route('assessments.index')->with('success', 'Assessment saved successfully.');
}
```

`// create.blade.php`
At the enter student scores part, I'm fetching all the available students from the student table and assign them their various scores.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <h3>Enter Scores of students</h3>
     @foreach($students as $index => $student)
       <label for="score-{{ $student->id }}">{{ $student->firstname }} {{ $student->lastname }}</label>
       <input type="number" class="form-control" id="score-{{ $student->id }}" name="score[{{ $student->id }}]" max="100" required>
      @endforeach
 </div>
```

`// Validation in StoreAssessmentRequest`

```
public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'assessment_name' => 'required',
            'score' => 'required|array',
            'score_over' => 'required|integer|min:0|max:100',
            'subject' => 'required|exists:subjects,name',
            'score.*' => 'required|integer|min:0|max:100',
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Then name of request input in validator is `scores` but you use `scores` in the foreach loop.

```php
foreach ($validated['score'] /* Change here to $validated['scores'] */ as $student_id => $score) {
            if($student = Student::findOrFail($student_id)){
            $assessment->students()->syncWithoutDetaching($student->id, ['score' => $score, 'subject_id' => $subject->id]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: My assessment table column has it as `score` without `s`, so what should I modify?

Comment: just change `$validated['score']` to `$validated['scores']` in the controller. You already doing it fine in attaching the tables

Comment: I did but now receiving this error `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'student_id' doesn't have a default value (Connection: mysql, SQL: insert into `assessments` (`assessment_name`, `score`, `score_over`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Homework1, 10,15, 20, 1, 2023-04-09 07:02:39, 2023-04-09 07:02:39))`.

Comment: I edit my answer. Add a condition before syncing the students.
if( $student = Student::findOrFail($student_id)){
            $assessment->students()->syncWithoutDetaching($student->id, ['score' => $score, 'subject_id' => $subject->id]);
}